# How does magento 2 control that the email have to be unique

Tags: magento2, email, login

I want to know how does magento 2 control that email exist or not  when creating an account because i have added  a custom attribute so that the customer can log in with his custom attribute(login) or with email but i can't find a way to make the custom attribute unique  i tried in installData and added the unique true but no result please any advice

Answer (score 2):

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

```
public function createAccountWithPasswordHash(CustomerInterface $customer, $hash, $redirectUrl = '')
{
```

Check following code snippet:

```
// This logic allows an existing customer to be added to a different store.  No new account is created.
// The plan is to move this logic into a new method called something like 'registerAccountWithStore'
if ($customer->getId()) {
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($customer->getEmail());
    $websiteId = $customer->getWebsiteId();

    if ($this->isCustomerInStore($websiteId, $customer->getStoreId())) {
        throw new InputException(__('This customer already exists in this store.'));
    }
    // Existing password hash will be used from secured customer data registry when saving customer
}
```

In table **customer_entity**, email and website_id is unique.

**[Update]**

**Create customer attribute and unique validation:**

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Setup;

use \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute as CustomerAttributeResourceModel;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavConfig
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var EavSetup
     */
    private $eavSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerAttributeResourceModel
     */
    private $customerAttributeResourceModel;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param EavConfig $eavConfig
     * @param EavSetup $eavSetup
     * @param CustomerAttributeResourceModel $customerAttributeResourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        EavConfig $eavConfig,
        EavSetup $eavSetup,
        CustomerAttributeResourceModel $customerAttributeResourceModel
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->eavSetup = $eavSetup;
        $this->customerAttributeResourceModel = $customerAttributeResourceModel;
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2', '<')) {
            $this->createUniqueAttribute($setup);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     */
    public function createUniqueAttribute($setup)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add new customer attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'unique_mobile',
            [

                'label'                 => 'Unique Mobile',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'required'              => false,
                'sort_order'            => 1000,
                'position'              => 1000,
                'visible'               => true,
                'system'                => false,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'default'               => '0',
                'user_defined' => false,
                'unique' => true,
                'backend' => 'SR\MagentoCommunity\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\UniqueMobile',
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'unique_mobile');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
        $this->customerAttributeResourceModel->save($attribute);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/UniqueMobile.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class UniqueMobile extends AbstractBackend
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepository
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
    }

    public function validate($customer)
    {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        $inputValue = $customer->getData($attributeName);
        /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
        $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
        $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($attributeName, $inputValue, 'eq');
        if ($customer->getId()) {
            $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('email', $customer->getEmail(), 'neq');
        }

        $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $customers = $this->customerRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        if (count($customers) > 0) {
            $label = $this->getAttribute()->getFrontend()->getLabel();
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The "%1" attribute value is Unique. Set the another value and try again.', $label)
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay just one thing i already put my custom attribute as unique but why do i still not having error with two account with same custom attribute

Comment: is there a thing that i miss and i have to add

Comment: You need to check that before saving. You can add backend model for validation. Email is static attribute so it's easy to validate through MySQL validation.

Comment: any example please and really thnaks a lot

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Clear cache, delete generated/*